# Convert a character digit to the corresponding integer in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

Is there a way to convert a character to an integer in C?

For example, from `'5'` to 5?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

As per other replies, this is fine:

```
char c = '5';
int x = c - '0';
```

Also, for error checking, you may wish to check isdigit(c) is true first. Note that you cannot completely portably do the same for letters, for example:

```
char c = 'b';
int x = c - 'a'; // x is now not necessarily 1
```

The standard guarantees that the char values for the digits '0' to '9' are contiguous, but makes no guarantees for other characters like letters of the alphabet.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: Yes for digits not letters, because, as I said in the answer, the standard guarantees '0' to '9' are contiguous but does not make such guarantees for other characters such as 'a' to 'z'.

Comment: char c = 'b';
int x = c - 'a'; then x will be 1 only in ASCII?

Comment: @Pan In any encoding, including ASCII, that has 'b' 1 more than 'a'. This still holds true in EBCDIC, however it makes ('j' - 'i') == 8.

Comment: @ChrisYoung Why? Cause in EBCDIC,'j' is not 1 more than 'i'?

Comment: What am I missing here where atoi isn't used?

Answer (score 51):

Subtract '0' like this:

```
int i = c - '0';
```

The C Standard guarantees each digit in the range `'0'..'9'` is one greater than its previous digit (in section `5.2.1/3` of the [C99 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)). The same counts for C++.

Comment: This answer would be better if you mentioned that a char is /already/ effectively an integer, albiet of implementation defined sign (ie, might be signed or unsigned), and is CHAR_BITS long.

Comment: i wasn't sure knowing that really helps him. but Chris made a good point with a..z being not contiguous necessarily. i should have mentioned that instead. now he's won the race :)

Comment: Yours is better because you've qualified your answer, though - Chris could very well have just made his stuff up. :)

Comment: thanks for the appreciation. i admit i wasn't sure about the state for C. so i looked up and 'cause i already was at it i pasted the reference into the answer :)

Comment: And that, sir, is why you've got a couple more points than me. :)

Comment: i believe you mate. i often find myself not pasting the reference to some standard section when giving answers either. but this time i looked up after answering and had the section numbers at hand, so it was easy to change my answer and add it in :) cheers

Answer (score 37):

If, by some crazy coincidence, you want to convert a *string* of characters to an integer, you can do that too!

```
char *num = "1024";
int val = atoi(num); // atoi = ASCII TO Int
```

`val` is now 1024. Apparently `atoi()` is fine, and what I said about it earlier only applies to me (on OS X (maybe (insert Lisp joke here))). I have heard it is a macro that maps roughly to the next example, which uses `strtol()`, a more general-purpose function, to do the conversion instead:

```
char *num = "1024";
int val = (int)strtol(num, (char **)NULL, 10); // strtol = STRing TO Long
```

`strtol()` works like this:

```
long strtol(const char *str, char **endptr, int base);
```

It converts `*str` to a `long`, treating it as if it were a base `base` number. If `**endptr` isn't null, it holds the first non-digit character `strtol()` found (but who cares about that).

Comment: There are no thread issues with atoi (it has no static data) and it is not deprecated. In fact it is functionally equivalent to: #define atoi(x) (int)(strtol((x), NULL, 10)

Comment: The issue with atoi is that it uses 0 as a "can't find a number here" value, so atoi("0") and atoi("one") both return 0.  If that doesn't work for what you're using it for, look for strtol() or sscanf().

Comment: The other advantage of strtol, of course, is that you may well need to read other things from the same string that come after the number.

Comment: @EvanTeran Unfortunately if you run Visual Studio you get a depreciation warning (and won&#39;t compile without being disabled).  VS now recommends `itoa_s()`.

Answer (score 19):

To convert character digit to corresponding integer. Do as shown below:

```
char c = '8';                    
int i = c - '0';
```

Logic behind the calculation above is to play with ASCII values. ASCII value of character 8 is 56, ASCII value of character 0 is 48. ASCII value of integer 8 is 8.

If we subtract two characters, subtraction will happen between ASCII of characters.

```
int i = 56 - 48;   
i = 8;
```

Comment: Why am I the only one to upvote this? The explanation is so simple and informative :+1:

Comment: Thank you, this explanation covers the fact that someone looking into this property of C may not connect the dots back to ASCII.  I came here straight from K&R, and they kind of gloss over this.

Answer (score 14):

Subtract char '0' or int 48 like this:

```
char c = '5';
int i = c - '0';
```

Explanation: Internally it works with [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value. From the ASCII table, decimal value of character **5 is 53** and **0 is 48**. So **53 - 48 = 5**

OR

```
char c = '5';
int i = c - 48; // Because decimal value of char '0' is 48
```

*That means if you deduct **48** from any numeral character, it will convert integer automatically.*

Answer (score 6):

```
char numeralChar = '4';
int numeral = (int) (numeralChar - '0');
```

Comment: `numeralChar - '0'` is already of type `int`, so you don't need the cast.  Even if it wasn't, the cast is not needed.

Comment: Huh, yeah that would coerce, wouldn't it?  Maybe Java has colored my perceptions.  Or maybe I'm completely mistaken and it would even coerce in Java. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are helper functions which allow to convert digit in char to int and vice versa:

```
int toInt(char c) {
    return c - '0';
}

char toChar(int i) {
    return i + '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `atol()`function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    const char *c = "5";
    int d = atol(c);
    printf("%d\n", d);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your digit is, say, `'5'`, in ASCII it is represented as the binary number `0011 0101` (53). Every digit has the highest four bits `0011` and the lowest 4 bits represent the digit in bcd. So you just do

```
char cdig = '5';
int dig = cdig & 0xf; // dig contains the number 5
```

to get the lowest 4 bits, or, what its same, the digit. In asm, it uses `and` operation instead of `sub`(as in the other answers).

Comment: `'5'` is 53(`00110101`)

Comment: @eyllanesc At first it was a 4. Thanks. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a single character 0-9 in ASCII, then subtracting the the value of the ASCII zero character from ASCII value should work fine.

If you want to convert larger numbers then the following will do:

```
char *string = "24";

int value;

int assigned = sscanf(string, "%d", &value);
```

** don't forget to check the status (which should be 1 if it worked in the above case).

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

```
char chVal = '5';
char chIndex;

if ((chVal >= '0') && (chVal <= '9')) {

    chIndex = chVal - '0';
}
else 
if ((chVal >= 'a') && (chVal <= 'z')) {

    chIndex = chVal - 'a';
}
else 
if ((chVal >= 'A') && (chVal <= 'Z')) {

    chIndex = chVal - 'A';
}
else {
    chIndex = -1; // Error value !!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do something like this I prebake an array with the values I want.

```
const static int lookup[256] = { -1, ..., 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, .... };
```

Then the conversion is easy

```
int digit_to_int( unsigned char c ) { return lookup[ static_cast<int>(c) ]; }
```

This is basically the approach taken by many implementations of the ctype library.
You can trivially adapt this to work with hex digits too.

Comment: That seems extremely inefficient for converting a single decimal (or octal) digit. If the relevant portion of your lookup table doesn't happen to be in L1 cache, you'll blow a bunch of cycles to pull it in just to get one value. Frankly, I tend to doubt this is even a good idea if you're converting a whole slew of digits, but you'd have to measure that. It's much more competitive for hex, of course.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this,**

```
char s='A';

int i = (s<='9')?(s-'0'):(s<='F')?((s-'A')+10):((s-'a')+10);
```

for only 0,1,2,....,E,F.

Answer (score -3):

You would cast it to an int (or float or double or what ever else you want to do with it) and store it in anoter variable.