# How to convert char to integer in C?

Tags: c, char, int

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to convert a single char into an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439573/how-to-convert-a-single-char-into-an-int)
>   [Character to integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628761/character-to-integer-in-c)

Can any body tell me how to convert a `char` to `int`?

```
char c[]={'1',':','3'};

int i=int(c[0]);

printf("%d",i);
```

When I try this it gives 49.

Comment: easiest is to do `int x = -1; if (isdigit(c)) {  x = c - 48; }`

Answer (score 162):

In the old days, when we could assume that most computers used ASCII, we would just do

```
int i = c[0] - '0';
```

<strike>But in these days of Unicode, it's not a good idea.  It was never a good idea if your code had to run on a non-ASCII computer.</strike>

Edit: Although it looks hackish, evidently it *is* guaranteed by the standard to work.  Thanks @Earwicker.

Comment: Not working .I expect answer as 1 but it gives a 6 digit nummber garbage i think

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to c[0] since that's what the example code uses.

Comment: How could unicode affect the representation of a digit in a char variable?

Comment: @David, you're probably right.  I was just thinking that there might be things in the Unicode character set that look like digits but aren't.  But really, the problem is other character sets, since the standard does not guarantee that 0-9 are contiguous integer values.

Comment: @Paul, actually the C standard does guarantee that. Paragraph 2.2.1 "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous." So your answer is perfectly valid in a conforming C implementation.

Comment: All digits in the Unicode class [Number, Decimal Digit](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) are continuous from 0 to 9. Example 0123456789, ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹, ߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉, ०१२३४५६७८९, ০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯, , , , , . Even EBCDIC has the digits continuous from 0 to 9. But if you are using Baudot, then you have a few problems...

Answer (score 41):

The standard function `atoi()` will likely do what you want.

A simple example using "atoi":

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int useconds = atoi(argv[1]); 
    usleep(useconds);
}
```

Comment: atoi takes a char* not a char.

Comment: Isn't that just semantics? A char* gives a char as well, just pass the address. But ok, I didn't look at the specifics, my C is starting to get kind of rusty.

Comment: If you pass &c to something expecting a null terminated string, you've going to be in a world of hurt.

Comment: Nope, to be correct, it expects a NULL-terminated char* not just an address.

Comment: @Frans,Noldorin: I would consider it very dangerous to "just" pass a pointer to a char array which isn't NULL terminated to a function expecting a NULL terminated string. In the example, remove the colon from the char array and the code will read uninitialized memory.

Comment: strtol is a better alternative these days.

Comment: Better use  [`strtol` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). atoi can return undefined behavior, if the number is out of int range.