# atoi function in K&R C book

Tags: c, getchar, atoi, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have some problems with an example of atoi() function from K&R C 2nd edition. Only characters from 0 to 9 should be used. But somewhere in the logic of my program I do something wrong.

So in there is this function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int atoi(char s[]);

int main()
{
    int i;
    char ch;
    char co[50]; 
    int  ci[50];

    while(ch != EOF )
    {

        for(i=0;i<50-1 && (ch=getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n';++i)
        {
            co[i] = ch;
            /*ci[i] = atoi(co[i]);*/ /*bugged*/
            ci[i] = atoi(co);
            printf("%d \n",ci[i]);
        }
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            co[i] = '\n';
        }
        ++i;
        co[i] = '\0';
    }

    return(0);

}

/* as in the book: */
/* atoi: convert s to integer */

int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n;
    n = 0;
    for(i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)
    {
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    }

    return(n);
}
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
|In function 'main':
19|warning: passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
3|note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char'
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Comment: That error message is chrystal clear.

Comment: @JimBalter That error message is chrystal clear. in fact, fixed, i was parssing the value in a wrong way. edited the main post.

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling, it should be "crystal". Please don't edit your code in place, because it means the answers don't make sense. Corrections should be added as an addendum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atoi();` function need pointer to string. `char*` that is the reason warning `warning: passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without typecase`

you declare co like: `char co[50];`  but calls `atoi(co[i]);` this is wrong,

notice it says int not char.

an example like:

`atoi("1");` is valid   but `atoi('1');`  not valid.

so even `co` is like `"12345678"` then `atoi(co)` correct but `atoi(co[i])` not correct.

Comment: took me a while to understand what you were saying :)

Comment: @CodrinH okh then two links are important for you (1) [How to convert char to integer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868496/how-to-convert-char-to-integer-in-c) and (2) [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars) You would find interesting.

Comment: i still try to understand why i definded the func `atoi(char s[])` and not just `atoi(char s)`, wich are the differences in this cases ?

Comment: @CodrinH First, do you understands `char co[10];` is not same as `char co;` fist is an array and it its null `'\0'` terminated it would be a string in C. Where as second is just a char variable. function `atoi()` excepts a string, and you can't pass a char variable to it. in-effect passing char to atoi() will be an error.

Comment: @CodrinH Welcome Codrin, Although I am not sure that I could explain you or not ...

Answer (score 2):

The

```
(s[i] = '0')
```

should read

```
(s[i] - '0')
```

(note the minus instead of the equals sign).

This converts the characters `'0'`..`'9'` to the numeric values `0`..`9`.

You are also not calling `atoi()` correctly. It takes a string, not a `char`. You should probably call it from outside the loop.

And `ch` isn't the right type (it should be `int`).

Comment: edit, that was a recent misstype. but is not the real problem

Comment: Another bug is that ch has the wrong type for the return value of getchar and comparing to EOF.

Comment: int atoi(char s[]), shouldn't this pass character by character ? as long as it gots the [], a function that waits for a string should be ( int atoi(char s) ?

Comment: @CodrinH NPE mentioned *two* problems.

Comment: @CodrinH You have a conceptual problem. Hopefully someone has the pedagogical skills and patience to explain in such a way as to get past your confusion.

Comment: @JimBalter i am shure about that :)

Comment: Another bug: `while(ch != EOF )` is UB because ch is uninitialized upon entering the loop.

Comment: @CodrinH No, that's not correct either. You probably want a `do { ... } while (ch != EOF)` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%c = ",co[i]);
ci[i] = atoi(co[i]);
printf("%d \n",ci[i]);
```

You are trying to convert a char to int, but a char *is* an integer value. All you need is

```
printf("%c = %d\n", co[i], co[i]);
```

if what you want is the decimal value of the char. If what you're trying to do is convert an ASCII digit to an integer, then

```
printf("%c = %d\n", co[i], co[i] - '0');
```

will do.

Comment: i managed this way:` int atoi(char s[])
{
    int n;

    n = (int)(s);

    return n;
}`

Comment: @CodrinH That makes no sense. I think you need to read and study K&R or some other C language tutorial until you have a better understanding of the language.