# Using getchar() to store a value to compare with an integer

Tags: c

i'm trying to count how many times a user inputs a certain digit and assign total number of instances to a location in a 10 row array  (0-9). For instance if the user inputs `888`, it will assign `3` to location arr1[8].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int arr1[10] = {0};
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
            if (c == i) // This isn't doing what I want it to do
                arr1[i] += 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    printf ("%c ", arr1[i]);
}
```

The trouble seems to be the line that i've added to comment above. The line `if (c == i)` is intended to compare a user inputed digit (as it's entered by the user, not the ASCII value) and compare it with `i`.

So how can I compare `c` and `i` as the same type? I've tried changing the type of `getchar()` to `char, signed int, unsigned int` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: have you looked at standard runtime function `isdigit()`? ctype.h

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert char to integer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868496/how-to-convert-char-to-integer-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to substract '0'.
2. You are printing char using `%c` for count.
3. You are incrementing by the count by `i` in the loop rather you wanted to increment by 1 for each character.

Corrected code:

```
    int main(void){
        int arr1[10] = {0};
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
                if (c - '0'  == i) 
                    arr1[i] += 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        printf ("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
```

Comment: yeah sorry, the `=+ i` was just a typo when I rewrote a simpler version for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform the following operation to convert the ASCII value to corresponding integer,

```
c=c-48;
```

Inside your for loop,

```
arr1[i] += i;
```

should be,

```
arr1[i] += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` will return ASCII code for `c`, not the numerical value. Simplest solutions exploits the fact that numbers 0-9 are sequential in the ASCII table, just subtract the offset:

```
int number = getchar() - '0';
if (number == i) {
    //....
}
```

This is just an example, always check the return value of `getchar` for error codes.

Finally, in this line:

```
printf ("%c ", arr1[i]);
```

Use `%d` as format specifier instead: you want to print a number, not a character.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int arr1[10] = {0};
    char table[] = "0123456789";
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
            if (c == table[i])//or table[i] --> "0123456789"[i]
                arr1[i] += 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        printf ("%d ", arr1[i]);
}
```