# How to subtract integers from characters in C?

Tags: c++, c, variables, char, int

Brian Kernighnan in his book Programming with C says

> By definition, chars are just small integers, so char variables and
>   constants are identical to ints in arithmetic expressions.

Does this mean we can subtract char variable from int ??

I wrote a small piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a ;
    int c;
    a = 1;
    c = 1 - '0' ;
    printf("%d", c);
}
```

However it gives me output = -47...

What is that I'm doing wrong ?? Are the variables I assigned have the right type??

Comment: Maybe you wanted `'1' - '0'`?

Comment: The result is correct. What result do you expect?

Comment: plus to the answers you need `%c` in `printf`

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868496/how-to-convert-char-to-integer-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output is to be expected. `'0'` is a `char` value that, since your compiler presumably uses the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding, has value 48. This is converted to `int` and subtracted from `1`. Which gives the value `-47`.

So the program does what it is expected to do, just not what you might hope it would do. As for what you are doing wrong, it is hard to say. I'm not sure what you expect the program to do, or what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Ok this makes it clear why I got answer as -47........But I'm still not sure do you mean to say yes to my question: can I subtract char and int ??

Comment: @ArchKudo Well yes, you just did. You substracted the char `'0'` from the int `1`. And you got back the int `-47`.

Comment: @ArchKudo The `char` is implicitly converted to an `int`, and then the subtraction is performed with two `int` values.

Answer (score 3):

The characters from `'0'-'9''` have values 48-57 when converted to integer ('0' = 48, '1' = 49 etc). Read more about [ASCII Values](http://www.asciitable.com/). When used in numerical calculation, first they are converted to `int`, so `1- '0' = 1-48 =-47`.

Comment: Oh that explains why I got SOH when I replaced it with %c

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing here the *actual operation* with the *form of representation*. `printf` outputs the data according to the specified format - integer in your case. If you want to print it as a character, switch `%d` with `%c`.

Comment: But didn't I define c as int so dosen't this mean I have to use %d in printf with respect to c which is an integer ?

Comment: @Adriano isn't that what I said?? (Did I Get you wrong??)

Comment: @ArchKudo yes, you're right. comment was for icepack! :)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That's exactly the point - `%d` defines the output format of the data you're printing, regardless of the data itself (which is just a block of 0s and 1s fom computer perspective and you choose how to interpret it according to your needs).

Comment: @icepack, Oh yes it does convert the int into char,when I had int a = 1 print with %c parameter it gives me SOH, I didn't knew about it thank you........

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is treating with the ASCII code of the chars, each char has an ASCII value assigned.

[image]

Now, playing a little with the ASCII of each char you can do things like:

```
int a;
a = 'a' - 'A' ;
printf("%d", a);
```

And get 32 as output, due to the ASCII value to 'a' = 97 and for 'A' = 65, then you have 97-65 = 32

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives you more clear understanding...

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a ;
    a = 1;
    printf("%d", char(a+48));
//or printf("%d", char(a+'0')); 
}
```