# Trying to recreate function atoi

Tags: atoi, recreate

I've problem in recoding function **atoi**. Here is the code *(just function body)*:

```
int atoi2(const char *s) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; isdigit('*s') == 1; s++) {
        sum = (sum * 10) + *s;
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Whenever i call function within parameter as string (like "12345"), i just get the **0**. Seems like it passes the for loop.

Meanwhile, yes i used the header

```
#include<ctype.h>
```

for using function **int isdigit(int)**.

Comment: You're always passing the integer value of '*s' to isdigit.

Comment: I tried it with (*s) but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems, one of which I hoped my comment would eliminate, so you could find the other one. First of all, you always call `isdigit` with the same value, instead of the current character in the string. That is fixed by removing the single quotes around `*s`. Secondly, you never actually do any conversion from the character to the number. For this, a little bit of knowledge about ascii is necessary (and some double checking if the standard is on your side: [How to convert char to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868496/how-to-convert-char-to-integer-in-c)). With those two corrections, your code should look like this and actually work:

```
int atoi2(const char *s) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; isdigit(*s); s++) {
        sum = (sum * 10) + (*s - '0');
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```