# How to store a big number in parts in an array and then add up the digits?

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

Let suppose a user enters a number below:

```
54353325421435
```

i want the variables below to store parts of the  number above

Eg.

```
int part[3]
part[0]=54353
part[1]=32
part[2]=5421435
```

and then add up the digits and store it the variable like below:

Eg.

```
int sum[3]
sum[0]=5+4+3+5+3      //sum up part[0]
sum[1]=3+2            //sum up part[1]
sum[2]=5+4+2+1+4+3+5  //sum up part[2]
```

Sorry guys! I don't know, how to explain this better! I hope you understand my question.
Thanks for reading

Comment: Have you read up on 4loops ,  also how much is each element suppose to store , and can you show us wat you have tried?

Comment: @amanuel2 i have no idea how to make this program! i am c++ beginner

Comment: The only way your gonna make a program is be first learning not giving you answers! [This](http://www.learncpp.com/) is a good tutorial.. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) are awesome guides on c++ books.

Comment: @amanuel2 yeah, i am leaning! i pretty much know the basics ! anyway thanks for websites! too!

Comment: Why do you guys! Vote down my page without giving to a reason!! So that i can improve next time!!!

Comment: Aravind : what i told you is what you need to improve on. Don't ask questions on SO , that says "How do you do this" .. Show us what you have tried , then we can help you from there onwards. And Learn C++ from good resources i listed . This problem won't be too difficult after then ;) . And most of all have fun learning C++!

Comment: @amanuel2 thats what! i exactly don't have no clue how to make this program! its not like i dont know anything about c++ ! i know all basics . eg till chapter 12 in your wedsite http://www.learncpp.com/! anyway leave that! how would you start if you r making a program like this??

Comment: I might give you an answer tomorrow. I will be giving cliff hangers for you to edit my Anwser and solve them.  You agree? Since I'm about too sleep now

Comment: @amanuel2 sure, !! thanks for effort!! i appreciate that!! btw! good night! (try to dreaming to solve it)

Comment: OK night.  Tell me how much numberless each array element is suppose to store?

Comment: @amanuel2 part[0]=54353 //thats is 5 digt,
part[1]=32 //thats is 2 digt, 
part[2]=5421435 //thats is 7 digt , make sure that i can change it in the future too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

You want to divide your integer to 3 different parts. Basically, you have a number `54353325421435`, and you want to divide it up into:

```
part[0]=54353
part[1]=32
part[2]=5421435
```

Then add them up.

### Solution

A `for` loop will do best. If you don't know what a `for` loop is, basically it's a means of iteration with a defined starting and ending point. For example, here is a simple iteration that prints out "hello world" 2 times:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;
```

You can learn more about `for` loops [**here**](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/57-for-statements/). In your case, what you want to do is iterate through this. So basically, first you store the variable in an integer. (I'm sure you can do that.)

```
 const unsigned long long NUM = 54353325421435; //Make it a constant to not change it
```

And then you have an array of parts as you mentioned above:

```
int part[3]
```

What you can do now is, loop through the `NUM`. So let me show you how to do the first one:

```
int access_digits(const unsigned long long int n, int index)
{
    int digit_array[64] = {0};

    unsigned long long digits = 0, digit, number = n;
    while (number) {
        digit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        digit_array[digits] = digit;
        digits++;
    }

    return digit_array[digits - index - 1];
}

 std::string digits;
 for(int i=0; i<=4; i++)
 {
    digits.append(std::to_string(access_digits(NUM,i)));
 }
 int digit_int = std::stoi( digits );
```

You can see above, first that there is an `access_digits` function. You can use that function to access digits by index. (Credit goes toward [**Slayther**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4936137/slayther).) Anyway, after that, you can see I am looping from 0 to 4 to get the first 5 digits for `part[0]`. The first 5 digits bring `54353`.

Now finally you want to add them up. Well, again that's pretty easy. Just loop through the digits, and have an accumulator add them up like so:

```
  int accum=0;
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    accum += access_digits(digit_int,i);
  }
```

### Exercise

Now edit this to include `part[1]` and `part[2]` below on the exercise section.

### References

[Iterating through digits in integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8671845/5768335)

[Teenage Territory chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85048)

[for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

[std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

[string::append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)

### Glossary

*For Loops*:

> Executes `init-statement` once, then executes `statement` and `iteration_expression` repeatedly until the value of `condition` becomes false. The test takes place before each iteration.

**Syntax**

> 

formal syntax:

> 

```
attr(optional) for ( init-statement condition(optional) ; iteration_expression(optional) ) statement
```

> informal syntax:

```
  attr(optional) for ( declaration-or-expression(optional) ; declaration-or-expression(optional) ; expression(optional) ) statement
```

Comment: thanks! i also made an another better method but still this is correct ! thx alot

Comment: @Aravind.KEN Edit my question so it contains your method! For future readers!

Answer (score -2):

if you want the sum of the digits of no. as you mentioned above then

```
int number,digit,sum=0;
while(number!=0)
{
 digit=number%10;
 sum=s+digit;
 number=number/10;
}
```

this code segment will calculate the sum of the digits of the no.

```
if number=123;
it will calculate sum=3+2+1=6;
```