# Converting a char to ASCII?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have tried lots of solutions to convert a char to Ascii. And all of them have got a problem.

One solution was:

```
char A;
int ValeurASCII = static_cast<int>(A);
```

But VS mentions that static_cast is an invalid type conversion!!!

PS: my A is always one of the special chars (and not numbers)

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c

Comment: int ValeurASCII = (int) A:

Comment: @Neppinger: Why even cast?!

Comment: An int and a char are the same thing, just different sizes in memory.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: not sure what this has to do with ASCII... which is just a simple mapping of the integer values 0..127 to various characters...

Comment: @user2187476 This is really easy, and there are lots of ways to do it (including the way you posted above). Because every way you've tried hasn't worked you must have some bigger problem. Post a complete program.

Answer (score 14):

A `char` is an integral type. When you write

```
char ch = 'A';
```

you're setting the value of `ch` to whatever number your compiler uses to represent the character `'A'`. That's usually the ASCII code for `'A'` these days, but that's not required. You're almost certainly using a system that uses ASCII.

Like any numeric type, you can initialize it with an ordinary number:

```
char ch = 13;
```

If you want do do arithmetic on a `char` value, just do it: `ch = ch + 1;` etc.

However, in order to display the value you have to get around the assumption in the iostreams library that you want to display `char` values as characters rather than numbers. There are a couple of ways to do that.

```
std::cout << +ch << '\n';
std::cout << int(ch) << '\n'
```

Answer (score 8):

Uhm, what's wrong with this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char **)
{
    char c = 'A';

    int x = c; // Look ma! No cast!

    cout << "The character '" << c << "' has an ASCII code of " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: int x = c; is casting. What you are doing here is implicit casting, because 'x' is integer and 'c' is char. It is equivalent to int x = (int) c, (which is an explicit cast)

Comment: @thinkquester **no**, that's **NOT** casting. There's a difference between *casting* and *converting*. A cast is something explicit that a programmer does. There are no "implicit casts".

Comment: Formally, this displays the value of `'A'` in whatever encoding the implementation uses. That's usually ASCII these days, but it's not required to be.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Thanks for pointing that out, it was a "hidden assumption" I should have made clear.

Comment: @NikBougalis - it's a hidden assumption that most programmers make.

Answer (score -1):

You can use chars as is as single byte integers.