# How can I go through a string entered by the user and return the same string 7 characters ascii forward?

Tags: c++

For example, if I introduce hello, the program through the ASCII table will return the same but character 7 letters forward: 'hello' -> 'olssu'.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried this but it obviously doesn't work:

```
  

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int asciiValue=65;
    string pass;
    cout<<"introduce la contraseña"<<endl;
    cin>>pass;
    char character = char(asciiValue+7);
    for(int a=0;a<pass.length();a++){
        
        cout<<character;
        cout<<pass[a];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a char to ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505375/converting-a-char-to-ascii)

Comment: why is it "obvious" that it doesn't work? And why is it then not obvious how to fix it? Nothing is really obvious...

Comment: what of `Zyuz` what should be the output?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, 'hello' would become 'olssv' moving ahead by 7 positions.
The code for achieving this would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string inputString;
    cin>>inputString;

    // iterate through the string
    for(int i=0; i< inputString.length(); i++) {
        
        // for each character, get its ASCII value
        // in C++, if you simply parse a character to an int
        // you will get the ASCII value
        int asciiValue = int(inputString[i]);

        // add 7 to the ascii value and print it as a char
        cout<<char(asciiValue + 7);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you `char` -> `int` -> `char` ? Is this really necessary?

Comment: Yes, Without parsing the asciiValue back to a char, it would simply print the ascii value as a number, not the character itself.

Comment: how about `intputString[i] + 7` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It would get implicit type converted to int and the entire result (after adding 7) gets printed as a number. If you wrap it up as char(inputString + 7), then it would work.

Comment: sorry, my comments were actually targeted at teasing some explanation out of you. I think you should explain a bit more in your answer what you changed on OPs code and why