# How cast char to int in C++? (File Handling)

Tags: c++, file-handling

Lets say I have a txt file `list.txt`

The txt file has list of integers ,

```
88
894
79
35
```

Now I am able to open the file and display the contents in it but not able to store it in an integer array.

```
int main()
{
     ifstream fin;
     fin.open("list.txt");
     char ch;
     int a[4],i=0;
     while((!fin.eof())&&(i<4))
     {
          fin.get(ch);
          a[i]=(int)ch;
          cout<<a[i]<<"\n";
          i++;
     }
     fin.close();
     return 0;
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: [Why looping on eof() is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert char to int in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `>>` to read text-formatted values:

```
fin >> a[i]
```

You should check for the end of the file *after* trying to read, since that flag isn't set until a read fails. For example:

```
while (i < 4 && fin >> a[i]) {
    ++i;
}
```

Note that the bound needs to be the size of the array; yours is one larger, so you might overrun the array if there are too many values in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
     const size_t N = 4;
     int a[N];

     std::ifstream fin( "list.txt" );

     size_t i = 0;

     while ( i < N && fin >> a[i] ) i++;

     while ( i != 0 ) std::cout << a[--i] << std::endl;

     return 0;
}
```