# Loading a Matrix into a 2D vector C++

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

I am new to using vectors in C++, my goal is to read a matrix from the text file and store them into a 2D vector, My code is as follows :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > v;

    if (in) {
        std::string line;

        while (std::getline(in, line)) {
            v.push_back(std::vector<int>());

            // Break down the row into column values
            std::stringstream split(line);
            int value;

            while (split >> value)
                v.back().push_back(value);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)
            std::cout << v[i][j] << ' ';

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

now for an input of say

```
10101010
01010101
10101011
01011010
```

I get an output of

```
10101010
1010101
10101011
1011010
```

i.e everytime a 0 is encountered in the beginning of a line it is omitted. I believe the problem is in the statement while(split>>value), but I dont know how to code it in a better way.

Comment: Leading 0's mean nothing to an integer so they are discarded.  Why not just store the strings?

Comment: I believe that is the problem because 0 is a logical false it is ommited, so how can I fix the code to include it ?

Comment: I took the input file string by string because it is faster than reading it character by character, but I want to apply matrix operations later on so I want them to be stored as integers.

Comment: Do you mean boolean instead of int? `10101010`, when read into an int, is a single integral value and not a series of integral values.

Comment: I tried using boolean as my vector type, but because I am new to using vectors I could not split the string or traverse the vector because I believe boolean works bit by bit instead of int which works in bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you actually want to store bits, but somehow struggled with parsing a line containing, for example, `10101010` into a series of bits.
If you know the maximum number of bits per line, you could use `bitset<N>`, which provide an easy to use overload for operator `>>` that can directly read in something like `10101010`. Hope it helps.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::vector<std::bitset<8> >v;

    if (in) {
        std::bitset<8> bits;
        while (in >> bits) {
            v.push_back(bits);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)
            std::cout << v[i][j] << ' ';

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Far better answer than mine

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
while (split >> value)
    v.back().push_back(value);
```

with

```
for(int x=0; x<line.size(); x++){
    v.back().push_back((int)line[x] - (int)'0'));
}
```

and remove your string stream completely.

Comment: can you explain the ' - (int)'0' ' part of the code please and thanks it worked

Comment: so the ASCII standard defines the numbers as character in order, 0 to 9 so casting the character to an int then subtracting the value for 0 gives you the value of the character.

Comment: Not a great explanation but look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)