# I want to replace letters with numbers in C

Tags: c, numbers, alphabet, letter

I would like to make some kind of program in C to encode and decode messages,now I successfully made the decoder,all I want it to do is if I ex. type "Hello" into an input.txt file I want it to print it as the letter's position in the alphabe as "8 5 12 12 15" to an output.txt file.All I did until now was I made a pretty simple decoder:

```
    if(a==1)
printf("a");
    if(a==2)
printf("b");
```

and so on... and I assigned space as 11111 in the decoder.
I am pretty new to C,I only learn it in school and have very basic knowledge.If anybody would be willing to explain it I would be very grateful.I would like to do it with a dictionary if possible.ex. [a]=1 [b]=2 so that if I want to I could change their number values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)

Comment: printf("%d ", ch - 'a' +1);