# barcode reader for Arduino recognize char

Tags: arrays, arduino, char, barcode-scanner

I have a barcode code but need it to recognize the barcode so it can print to serial monitor. I have searched that I need to have it convert to int from char but have yet to find a way to do that if that is the answer.

For example I scan a barcode and if it is a certain number, then the serial monitor will print it.

```
#include <hid.h>
#include <hiduniversal.h>
#include <usbhub.h>
#include <Usb.h>
#include <hidboot.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <FileIO.h>
#include <TM1637Display.h>

#define DEBUG true

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);

const byte BarcodeLength = 11;
const int buzzer = 2;


const int CLK = 9; //Set the CLK pin connection to the display
const int DIO = 8; //Set the DIO pin connection to the display
const int DIO2 = 7; // Set 2nd DIO pin to second connection to display
const int CLK2 = 6; // Set the 2nd CLK pin to the second connection to display. 
const int procTime = 5; // this is the time it takes for the process to finish countdown


int NumStep = 0;  //Variable to interate

TM1637Display countdownDisplay(CLK, DIO);  //set up the 4-Digit Display.
TM1637Display DelayedDisplay(CLK2, DIO2);  //set up the 4-Digit Display.


class BarcodeReader : public KeyboardReportParser
{
    USB Usb;
    USBHub Hub;
    HIDUniversal Hid;
    HIDBoot<HID_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD> Keyboard;

    uint8_t buffer[15];
    byte length;
    bool valid;

    void addCharacter(uint8_t c);

  public:
    BarcodeReader();
    void begin();
    void task();
    const uint8_t* barcode();
    void reset();

  protected:
    virtual void OnKeyDown(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
};

BarcodeReader::BarcodeReader()
  : Usb()
  , Hub(&Usb)
  , Hid(&Usb)
  , Keyboard(&Usb)
  , length(0)
  , valid(false)
{
}

void BarcodeReader::begin()
{
  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.println("OSC did not start.");
  }
   else 
 Serial.println("Barcode Ready");

  Hid.SetReportParser(1, this);
}

void BarcodeReader::task()
{
  Usb.Task();
}

void BarcodeReader::addCharacter(uint8_t c)
{
  if (valid) {
    // already have a barcode, new one will overwrite it
    reset();
  }

  // could check for \n or \r if necessary, or even implement a timing
  // mechanism for detecting end of barcode input, but for now we just
  // assume fixed width field with no output separators

  buffer[length++] = c;
  //buffer[length] = '\0';

  if (buffer[length] == '\0') 
  {
    valid = true;
  }
};

// return value no longer valid after another call to task()
const uint8_t* BarcodeReader::barcode()
{
  return (valid) ? buffer : 0;
}

void BarcodeReader::reset()
{

  length = 0;
  valid = false;
}

void BarcodeReader::OnKeyDown(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
  uint8_t c = OemToAscii(mod, key);
  if (c) addCharacter(c);
}

BarcodeReader barcodeReader;

void setup() {

  countdownDisplay.showNumberDec(0);
  DelayedDisplay.showNumberDec(0); 

 Bridge.begin();
  Console.begin();
  FileSystem.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (DEBUG) Console.println("Done setup");



  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);
  //Serial.begin(115200); 

   lcd.print("Please Scan Your ID: ");
  barcodeReader.begin();


  countdownDisplay.setBrightness(0x0a);  //set the diplay to maximum brightness
  DelayedDisplay.setBrightness(0x0a);
 }

void loop() {
  //char *goodCards = { "1234567" };
 //String dataString = "Testing, 1, 2, 3...";


  File dataFile = FileSystem.open("/mnt/sda1/datalog.txt", FILE_APPEND);
  // If the file opens successfully, write the string to it, close the file,
  // and print the information to the Serial monitor.


  barcodeReader.task();
  const char* barcode = barcodeReader.barcode();
  if  (barcode || dataFile) {  

        lcd.print(barcode);
         dataFile.print(barcode);
        Serial.print(barcode);  
        barcodeReader.reset();
         dataFile.close(); 
//If the barcode is the word 'Setup' then print setup to the screen
//search array of char conver strcmp(). You are sending 0101 not the actual value of 1234567
// collect all the input, convert it to an int
          if(barcode == "0001") {
             {

    Serial.println(": SETUP");

  }
    }   

  }


//timer and barcode


//
// if(barcode == "1234567") {
//    Serial.print(barcode);
//    Serial.println(": SETUP");
// 
////     analogWrite(A1,0);
////    analogWrite(A2,0);
//  }
//   if(barcode == "KAYAMAD") {
//    Serial.print(barcode);
//    Serial.println(": RUN");
//    
////     analogWrite(A0,0);
////    analogWrite(A2,0);
//       countdownDisplay.showNumberDec(0);
//  DelayedDisplay.showNumberDec(0);
//      for(int NumStep = procTime; NumStep > 0 ; NumStep--)  //Interrate NumStep
//  {
//    countdownDisplay.showNumberDec(NumStep); //Display the Variable value;
//    //DelayedDisplay.showNumberDec(NumStep); //Display the Variable value;
//    delay(1000);  //A second delay between steps.
//  }
//  
//      for (int NumStep = 0; NumStep < 5 ; NumStep++)  //Interrate NumStep
//  {
//    //countdownDisplay.showNumberDec(NumStep); //Display the Variable value;
//    DelayedDisplay.showNumberDec(NumStep); //Display the Variable value;
//    countdownDisplay.showNumberDec(0);
//    delay(1000);  //A second delay between steps.
//    
//  }
//    
//  }
//  
//  else if (barcode == "2234663") {
//    Serial.print(barcode);
//    Serial.println(": DELAY");
//   
////      analogWrite(A0,0);
////    analogWrite(A1,0);
//     countdownDisplay.showNumberDec(0);
//  DelayedDisplay.showNumberDec(0);
//  
//
//      for (int NumStep = 0; NumStep < 5 ; NumStep++)  //Interrate NumStep
//  {
//    //countdownDisplay.showNumberDec(NumStep); //Display the Variable value;
//    DelayedDisplay.showNumberDec(NumStep); //Display the Variable value;
//    countdownDisplay.showNumberDec(0);
//    delay(1000);  //A second delay between steps.
//    
//  }
//
//
//  }
//  

  // If there is a problem opening the file, send an error to the Serial monitor
  else {
    if (DEBUG) Console.println("Error opening datalog.txt");
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)

Comment: tried this but it didnt work. If anyone has any other ideas to get the barcode reader to recognize it

Answer (score 0):

"Number" you get Computer sees as text, not number. We are sure that barcode will always be number. Conver char to int with `atoi` function.
Here's an example:

```
const char *bar = "123";
int bc = atoi(bar);
```

Comment: stoi doesn't work with arduino. It is telling it was not declared in the scope

Comment: Include string library

Comment: is there a link because I can't find it on githb

Comment: Just add #include <String>

Comment: I edited anwser. You don't need library for this function