# C++ convert char to int

Tags: c++

Sorry for my bad English. I need to build app which converts hex to rgb. I have file U1.txt with content inside:

```
2 3
008000
FF0000
FFFFFF
FFFF00
FF0000
FFFF00
```

And my codeblocks app:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    string color;

    ifstream data("U1.txt");
    ofstream result("U1result.txt");

    data >> a;
    data >> b;

    for (int i = 0; i < a * b; i++) {
        data >> color;
        cout << color[0] * 16 + color[1] << endl;
    }

    data.close();
    result.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me `816`. But it should be 0. I think color[0] is not an integer, but a char and it multiplies by ASCII number.. I've tried many ways with atoi, c_str() and it not working. P.S do not suggest stoi(), because I need to do this homework with older C++. Thanks in advance and have a good day ;)

Comment: I think you're looking for [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)

Comment: @Mgetz Thank you! But anyway I need to do this in my way :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)

Comment: While I appreciate you accepting my answer, you really should wait a while. Once a question has an accepted answer many people don't bother to read it, so you might miss out on additional information or perhaps an even better answer. Give it a day or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those encodings use 24 bits, you have to start out with an integer type that holds at least 24 bits. And for this kind of packing and unpacking, it really ought to be unsigned, so you don't get tangled up in sign bits. That means using `std::uint_least32_t`, which is the smallest unsigned type that can hold at least 32 bits. (Yes, 24 would fit better, but there is no least24 type; 32 is the best you can do).

If your compiler doesn't provide those fixed-width types (`std::uint_least32_t`), you can use `unsigned long`. It's required to be at least 32 bits wide. It could be larger, and the reason for using `std::uint_least32_t` is that your compiler might have, for example, a 32-bit integer, in which case `unsigned int` would be 32 bits wide. But you can't count on that, so either use the fixed-width type or use `unsigned long` to ensure that you have enough bits.

Since the character inputs are encoded in hexadecimal, you need to tell the input system to interpret them as hex values. So:

```
std::uint_least32_t value;
data >> std::hex >> value;
```

Now you've got the value in the low 24 bits of `value`. You need to pick out the individual R, G, and B parts of that value. That's straightforward. To get the low 8 bits, just mask out the higher ones:

```
std::cout << (value & 0xFF) << '\n';
```

To get the next 8 bits, shift and mask:

```
std::cout << ((value >> 8) & 0xFF) << '\n';
```

And, naturally, to get the upper 8 bits, shift and mask:

```
std::cout << ((value >> 16) & 0xFF) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly store the hexadecimal values in an `int` with `std::hex`.

```
int b;
ifstream data("U1.txt");
data >> std::hex >> b;
```

Comment: Thank you! It is impossible to do this in any other way? Char > int..?

Comment: Note that this code assumes that `int` is at least 24 bits; while that's common these days, it is not required. In particular, many embedded systems use 16-bit `int`.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do this in your case.

Answer (score -1):

A rather unelegant but also working answer is to subtract all your chars by 48 as thats where numbers start in ASCII. This is also the reason why you get 816 as:

```
48*16+48 = 816
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks, good answer but still be looking for more "elegant" :)

Comment: NO, NO, NO! That **seems** to work because 48 is the ASCII code for `'0'` and you're only looking at the character `'0'`. Try it for `'F'`. (Note that, in general, you can subtract `'0'` from any of the characters `'0'..'9' and get the value that the character represents; the C and C++ language definitions require this to work. They do not impose any other requirements on the values involved in character encodings).

Comment: I am a bit confused about your comment, I honestly believed 'int x = (int)character - 48' and 'int x = character - '0'' were interchangable… Will try this out as soon as I get a chance to.

Comment: @NewEyes -- they'll do the same thing on a system that uses ASCII, which is almost certainly true for yours. Some systems use a different encoding, and `'0'` is not 48 (read about [EBCDIC](http://www.astrodigital.org/digital/ebcdic.html)). More important, subtracting `'0'` **won't convert** a character like `'F'` to the value that it represents.

Comment: Did some research, turns out you are right! Thanks for enlighting me