# C Programming: fgets() function is not reading the values that I think it should

Tags: c, io, fgets

I am trying to open and read a .txt file that simply contains a 2 digit number from 00 to 99.

Currently the file contains the following numbers: 05

When I read the first two values with fgets(), I instead get 48 and 53, and I've noticed whatever number I put in there, the number that fgets() grabs is 48 higher.  While I could just subtract 48 from the number like I am doing now, I would like to figure out what I am doing wrong so that I don't have to do that.  Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
char buff[3];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("savedata/save.txt","r");
fgets(buff, 3, fp);
SampleLevelIndex = (buff[0]-48)*10 + buff[1]-48;
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: 48 is the ASCII code for the character `'4'`. `fgets` does not read numbers. It reads characters. Why don't you use `fscanf`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)

Comment: So I tried casting it to an int after I read it but that didn't seem to work.  Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You cannon cast a digit character to the numeric value that it represents. See a link to the possible dupe.

Comment: @JakeWard casting is not the same as converting from ascii to integer. atoi / atol will do it

Comment: That looks like it'll do the trick, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contain the characters '0' and '5'. Note that the ASCII code for '0' is 48.

You are reading the values of the bytes, not the number represented. If you had an 'A' in the file, you would have the byte 65.

Your approach works for manually converting numeric characters into a number (although you might one some extra checking, it will break if it doesn't contain two numbers). Or you could use a function like `atoi()` which converts a numeric string into the number.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I'll be using atoi() now.

Comment: No!  `atoi` invokes undefined behavior on certain inputs.  Use a safe function like `strtol`