# Can Someone explain this Program ? I don't understand it

Tags: c++, computer-science

This is the program for converting the ascii sentence to character sentence. But i dont understand the ***num = num * 10 + (str[i] - '0');***  why it us used and why it's needed?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
void asciiToSentence(string str, int len) 
{ 
    int num = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        num = num * 10 + (str[i] - '0'); 
        if (num >= 32 && num <= 122) { 
            char ch = (char)num; 
            cout << ch; 
            num = 0; 
        } 
    } 
}
int main() 
{ 
    string str = "973265"; 
    int len = str.length(); 
    asciiToSentence(str, len); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why bother understanding it? [Doesn't compile.](https://godbolt.org/z/sGKf6o)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that compiles properly.

Comment: `num = num * 10 + (str[i] - '0');` this is converting a number in a `char *` to an `int`. the code after is just bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `bits/*` are not standard headers, you shouldn't be using them otherwise your code may not compile with compilers like MSVC. [Refer this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Now let's come to your query : `str[i] - '0'` is simply a way to convert `char` to respective `int`, i.e. `'0'` to `0`. You can find more discussion on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5029840/11613622).

**What does your code do?**

It just keeps on extracting chars from your string (in loop), converting it to `int` and adding to `num` after multiplying it by `10`. This is basically converting a part of string, say, `"97"` to an integer `97`.

When `num` comes in range from `32` (`' '`) to `122` (`'Z'`) (both inclusive), it cast them to `char` and prints it.

**Explanation of Sample Output:**

Your code prints `a A` to console. You will get this result if you can figure out the substrings. Here consider these three - `"97" "32" "65"`. Then `"97"` will be converted to `97` (as `int`), then will be cast to `char` and end up being `'a'` (`'a'` has ASCII value of `97`). Similarly `"32"`, will be a space `' '`, and `"65"` will be `'A'`.

---

These substrings didn't come here by magic. Let me explain one for you :

You have `str = "973265"`, `num = 0`, then the loop begins :

`i = 0` -> `str[i] = '9'` -> `str[i] - '0' = 9` ->  `num = 0*10 + 9 = 9` -> is num in range `[32, 122]`? `false` -> go to next iteration.

`i = 1` -> `str[i] = '7'` -> `str[i] - '7' = 7` ->  `num = 9*10 + 7 = 97` -> is num in range `[32, 122]`? `true` -> `ch = (char)num = (char)97 = 'A'` -> print `ch`, i.e. `'A'` -> `num = 0` -> go to next iteration.

---

*Pro Tip:* Use your debugger, set breakpoints, watch variables and step through your code for better understanding.

*Note that:* When I wrote ____ - I meant ____ like this ____.

- "convert" -- conversion -- `'0' <-> 0` or `"12" <-> 12`
- "cast" -- casting -- `'0' <-> 48` (assuming your compiler is using ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

In http://www.asciitable.com/, you can see that `0` has ascii value of 48, `1` is 49, `2` is 50 and so on.

So `str[i] - '0'` will give you 0 if `str[i] == '0'`, 1 if `str[i] == '1'` and so on. This is a simple trick to convert numeric char into its mathematical value.

Let's call `str[i] - '0'` as `x`, so the line you don't understand becomes `num = num * 10 + x`. What this does is, take the original `num` (say it was `32`), add a `0` behind it (so it becomes `320`), then add `x` (if `x` is 7, `num` becomes `327`).

So overall, this code is basically a function that converts a number string into integer type.

Comment: Interesting fun fact: The ASCII value of `'0'` is irrelevant. `str[i] - '0'` will result in 0 no matter the encoding for any compliant C++ implementation. Unfortunately the `char ch = (char)num;` may not work if the character encoding is not sufficiently ASCII-like to encode the the alphabet with the same values.