# From where is extra 48 is coming from?

Tags: c++

This is the code I wrote for finding the sum of any integer that is inside a string. (for example, `hello56` should give answer `11`)

BUT,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define ll long long
#define ull unsigned long long

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int t;
    int sum;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            if (isdigit(s[i])) {
                sum = sum + s[i];
            }
        }
        cout << sum << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but this code adds `48` for every integer in the string (for `hello56` it gives `107`) and if I change `sum=sum+s[i];` to `sum=sum+s[i]-48;` it works,
WHY?

Comment: Take a closer look here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: youre adding up the (likely ascii) values of the characters not their numerical digit value, `sum += s[i] - '0';` should do the trick

Comment: In other words, character `'0'` is actually the number 48.

Comment: Please only tag the languages you are using, this is not `c` code

Comment: @JaMiT yes it does, but i have already got the answer, thank you everyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c)

Comment: @MujtabaHussain You might notice that I deleted my earlier comment (well before you replied). I did that because I realized I had misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

Program is printing the `ascii` value of 5+6.

```
'5'=53
'6'=54
so 53 + 54 = 107.
```

In order to convert char to number you can use `s[i]-'0'`.

```
'5' - '0' = 5
'6' - '0' = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

`48` is the ASCII value of character `0`: `sum = sum + s[i] - '0';` computes the sum of the digits.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up integers and characters, as you can see in following code excerpt:

```
   int sum;
   ...
        string s;
   ...
                sum = sum + s[i];
```

A string consists of characters, which can be letters, digits or punctuation marks. You are taking the sum of an integer and a character. When doing that, the integer "translation" of the character is taken, which is better known as the ASCII code.

The ASCII codes for the digits are the following:

```
character  ASCII code
      '0'          48
      '1'          49
      '2'          50
      '3'          51
      '4'          52
      '5'          53
      '6'          54
      '7'          55
      '8'          56
      '9'          57
```

As you can see, you get the following interpretation:

```
ASCII_Code(character) = meaning(character) + 48
```

When you are doing `sum = sum + s[i]`, then `s[i]` is the same as `ASCII_Code(i)`, which explains your problem.

Therefore, in order to know the meaning of a character, you can do the following:

```
meaning(character) = ASCII_Code(character) - 48              // or clearer:
meaning(character) = ASCII_Code(character) - ASCII_Code('0')
```

Comment: Re: "or clearer:" -- better is "better, because portable:". The C and C++ standards require that the characters `'0'..'9'` must be contiguous and increasing. So for **every** valid character encoding (not just ASCII), `character - '0'` gives the numeric value that the (digit) character represents.

Comment: @PeteBecker: you are free to edit my answer accordingly. I was just using `ASCII_Code()` as this is the mostly used encoding.

Answer (score 0):

In all standardised character sets the character `'0'` (which prints as a zero on screen) has a non-zero numeric value.

There are a number of reasons for this - including the convention (used in C) of using a character with numeric value of `0` being used to mark the end of a string of characters.   This convention, if `'0'` had a numeric value of zero, mean that it would not be possible to represent a value like `100` as a string (every digit `'0'` would mark the end of the string).

In character sets compatible with ASCII, `'0'` has a numeric value of `48`.   There are standardised character sets with `'0'` having a different numeric value.

Fortunately, in all standardised character sets, the arabic numerals (`'0'`, `'1'`, .... `'9'`) are a contiguous set so, if `x` is a character containing an arabic numeral,  `x - '0'` will convert `x` to its corresponding numeric value  (e.g. `'0' - '0'` gives an integral value of `0`, `'1' - '0'` is `1`, etc).

So, when examining digits presented in a string, it is necessary to subtract `'0'` from each to convert it to its numeric value.    For example, adding the characters of `"12"` as `10*'1' + '2'` will (for an ASCII character set) give a value of `540`, but subtracting `'0'` from each character (i.e.  `10*('1' - '0') + ('2' - '0'`) will give `12`.

This can be demonstrated in the following code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
      char digit = '0';

      std::cout << digit << '\n';          // will print 0 (followed by newline)
      std::cout << (int)digit << '\n';     //  for an ASCII character set will print 48

      std::string test = "12";

      int incorrect_sum = 0;
      int correct_sum = 0;

      for (const auto c : test)
      {
           incorrect_sum *= 10;
           incorrect_sum += c;

           correct_sum *= 10;
           correct_sum += c - '0';    // note the correction here
      }

      std::cout << incorrect_sum << ' ' << correct_sum << '\n';  // will print 540 and 12

}
```