# Totally unrelated result when multiplying two integers?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
        
int main(void) {
    std::string fx = "6x^2+6x+4";
        
    int part1 = fx[0] * fx[3];
                cout << fx[0] << endl;
                cout << fx[3] << endl;
                cout << part1;
}
```

So I have this string and `fx[0]` and `fx[3]` are obviously integers: when I print them to the console they print out just fine; however, `part1` (their multiplication) equals some totally unrelated number? Can anyone help?

Here is the output:

```
6
2
2700
```

Comment: `fx[0] and fx[3] are obviously integers` are you sure about that?

Comment: convert them to int

Comment: ASCII `'6'` is 0x36 (54) and ASCII `'2'` is 0x32 (50). `54 * 50 == 2700`. By the way, [please do not post images of text because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Text should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Your `fx[0]` and `fx[3]` variables are of type `char` (which *is* an integer type in C++). However, the *actual values* in those two elements of your `fx` string will be representations of the digits, `6` and `2`, not the numerical values of those digits.

Very often, those representations will be [ASCII codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (but that's not required); however, what *is* required is that the representations of the digits `0` thru `9` have contiguous, sequential values. Thus, by subtracting the value of the digit, `0`, we can convert to their numerical representations.

In your case, the following line will do the conversion:

```cpp
    int part1 = (fx[0]-'0') * (fx[3]-'0');
```

The reason why you see the correct values when printing `fx[0]` and `fx[3]` is because the version of the `cout <<` operator that takes a `char` argument is *designed* to print the represented character (not its 'ASCII' code); however, the `cout <<` operator for an `int` type (like your `part1`) will print the actual value represented internally. (Try changing one of your lines to `cout << (int)fx[0] << endl;` to see the difference.)

---

P.S. Don't forget the `#include <string>` header – some implementations do that *implicity* inside the `<iostream>` header, but don't rely on that!

Answer (score 2):

Characters are values representing glyphs from some representation, usually the ASCII table.  The numeric value of a character is not the same as the glyph that is printed on the screen.  To convert a numeric-looking char to an actual "0-based" numeric value, subtract '0' from your char value.

(fx[3]-'0']) will be the numeric value of character represented at position 3.

Comment: "numbers contiguously represented" - the standard insists on this.

Comment: That is why it is a safe assumption.  :)  Fixed via removal.

Answer (score 2):

well, first of all, `string::operator[]` returns a `char`... then, a `char` can be casted to an `int`, and the cast works checking the ID in the ASCII table (in your case)

In ASCII, the ID of `"6"` and `"2"` are respectively `54` and  `52` (you can check it [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alpharithms.com%2Fascii-table-512119%2F&psig=AOvVaw2SGuITC7TOlpWatXa3ts0Q&ust=1627742131102000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCPjJtI6Ci_ICFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) for example)... so your program is taking the two `char`, casting them to `int`, and multiplying them (54 * 50 = 2700)

If you need to interpret those as the integer value they represent, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c):

```
int val = '6' - '0'; // val == 6
```

Comment: The character encoding is not involved in the promotion of a `char` value to an `int`. The conversion from text to integer values is done by the compiler when it converts the **text** `"6x^2+6x+4"` into `char` values.

Comment: And note that there are no casts in this code. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The compiler converts `char` values to `int` in arithmetic expressions on its own; no casts involved.

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying character types. so the characters '6' and '2' will converted to its integer values 54 and 50 respectively then multiplication is applied. This works based on C++ type conversion rule. Then you will get 2,700. Try the modified sample code

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(void) {
    std::string fx = "6x^2+6x+4";

    int part1 = fx[0] * fx[3];
    cout << fx[0] << endl;
    cout << fx[3] << endl;
    cout << part1;
    cout << std::endl;
    cout << (int)fx[0] << " " << (int)fx[3] << std::endl;
}
```

And the results

```
6
2
2700
54 50
```

Comment: *You are multiplying character types.* Not really - the `char` operands are promoted to `int` before the multiplication.

Comment: That is what I meant actually

Comment: Re: "converted ... then multiplication" -- that's not the sequence. The compiler uses the character encoding when it converts `"6x^2+6x+4"` to a sequence of `char` values, which is stores in `fx`. For the multiplication, the values stored in `fx[0]` and `fx[1]` are simply promoted to `int`.