# C++: Dividing double from string index gives incorrect answer

Tags: c++, division

I am trying to divide a digit in a string which is selected by its index by 10. But instead of giving me 0.x, it provides me a different answer.

Here is an example to reproduce the error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string y = "2";
    double x = y[0];
    cout << x/10.0 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `'2' != 2`. Try: `y[0] - '0'`.

Comment: In  addition to what @Evg said: [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c) which explains the meaning of `y[0] - '0'`

Comment: `... / 10.0` will do such a conversion for you. `x` could be of type `int`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't divide strings, you need to convert it to an integer.

Comment: OP doesn't divide strings. They divides `double`s.

Comment: @Evg OP divides a value originally of type `char`, and read in as a character, by a `double`, so @Benjamonster is not completely wrong

Comment: @codeling `x` has type `double`. `x / 10.0` is a division of two `double`s.