# Char array index

Tags: c++, arrays, char

could someone try explain the what the difference between these two pieces of codes is?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char keypad[10][5]={"","","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"};
    int idx = 2;
    string digits = "1324";
    int curidx=digits[idx] - '0';
    
    cout << curidx << endl;

}
```

In this case, with the inclusion on line 12, the output is 2.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char keypad[10][5]={"","","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"};
    int idx = 2;
    string digits = "1324";
    int curidx=digits[idx];// - '0';
    
    cout << curidx << endl;

}
```

In this result, the output result is 50. What does the inclusion of `- '0'` do?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii and notice the relationship between the numeric digits. If you subtract `'0'` from any of them it gives you the numeric value.

Comment: [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c) covers a lot of things, but has a few answers that explain it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In `C` and `Cpp`, everything is inherently treated as a "number". Even `char` manipulations should be treated as number-operations...that makes it easier to logic-out the requirements.

Every `char` is indeed, an integer, equivalent to its `ASCII` value.

Hence, `'2' = 50`. Also, `'A' = 65` and `'a' = 97` and so on...

So, your operation `'2' - '0'` actually does `50-48`, which results in `2`

When you do not subtract and print `'2'` as integer, it prints its ascii value, which is `50`. If you would print it as a `char` or `string`, it would have printed `2`.

Comment: Noteworthy, that this is guaranteed for other character encoding tables as well, e.g. EBCDIC. And totally relies on the fact, that numeric decimal digits have consecutive number encodings.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ does any language use EBSDIC as default char-encoding?

Comment: There are still terminals present, I believe it's mostly in banking sector.