# C++ redefinition in while loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, char, integer

I'm trying to make a loop that asks coordinates from the user, and then prints those coordinates if they are in range of [1, 3]. If they are out of range, it prints error message. If input is 'q' it prints "Quitting".

I have defined x and y as int, but 'q' is char. How this kind of redefinition should be done?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x; int y;

    while (true) {
    cout << "Enter coordinates (x, y): ";
    cin >> x >> y;

    if (x >= 1 && x <= 3 && y >= 1 && y <= 3) {
        cout << "Removing " << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
    else if (char x = 'q') {
        cout << "Quitting" << endl;
        break;    
    }
    else cout << "Out of board" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `x = 'q'` with `x == 'q'` and remove `char x = 'q'`. That is, you have a **typo**.

Comment: You can't. `cin >> x >> y;` will fail if the input is not an integer, and since you're not checking for errors it will go unnoticed. `while (cin >> x >> y) { ... }` would keep going while integers were entered and exit the loop if a character or EOF was entered. Another way is to perform all of the input into strings and parse them or check for "q".

Answer (score 0):

The main problem hides in this expression here:

```
else if (char x = 'q')
```

It seems like you want to cast variable x to the `char` type and check whether it is equal to 'q'.
First of all, if you were to cast a variable, the type needs to be wrapped in brackets.
Second, you`ll have to use the equality operator `==`, single `=` is an assignment operator.

One possible solution may look like this:

```
else if ((char) x == 'q')
// ...
```

Comment: But you need to enter the integer that is the encoding of 'q' (probably 113) rather than 'q'...

Comment: Changing char x = 'q' to (char) x == 'q' does give "Out of board" when input is q, it should give "Quitting" and end the program

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach would simply ask the user to enter "q" in a separate prompt. You're asking for input into an int:

```cpp
int x; int y;
cin >> x >> y;
```

And then checking if the user entered a char i.e. 'q' :

```
else if (char x == 'q') // == for comparison
```

What you can do is use a temporary variable to initially store x as a char, check if it is q and then move on:

```cpp
    char tempX;
    cin >> tempX;
    if ( tempX == 'q' ) {
        cout << "Quitting" << endl;
        break;  
    }
    x = tempX - '0'; // for converting tempX to an int.
    cin >> y;
```

For more on the char conversion, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c).