# What is the meaning of this expression

Tags: c++, string, stack, github-copilot

I am trying to push a integer that is stored in a string to a stack of type int I was trying to do the same by using stack.push(str[i]) which resulted in some weird values in the final outcome

Github copilot suggeted to do it this way which was succesfull

```
else
       {
           temp.push(exp[i]-'0');
       }
```

what is the meaning of -'0' here

Comment: Likely a dupe of [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c), but you haven't provided a [mcve], so it's hard to tell what you are talking about.

Comment: This should be explained, somewhere, in every C++ textbook. "github copilot" is not a replacement for a C++ textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The char '0' has ascii value 0x30 (48 decimal).

The char '9' has ascii value 0x39 (57 decimal).

If you do `'9' - '0'` = `57 - 48` = `9`.

So you are converting a digit from its ascii number `'9' = 57` to its numeric value `9`.

This is often used when fast-converting a string of integers to its numeric value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the subtle explaination.

Comment: Side note: This trick is guaranteed to work with all character encodings allowed by C++, not just ASCII.