# convert str[i] into integer type using stoi()

Tags: c++, string, stoi

I have a string of number and I want to convert each number into integer type then add it into a vector.

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    #include<string>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        vector<int> vec;
        string num;
        cin >> num;
        for(int i = 0; i <= num.length(); i++){
            vec.push_back(stoi(num[i]));
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

it said error: no matching function for call to stoi

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c

Comment: `i <= num.length(); num[i]` that is nice buffer overflow, although likely safe due `\0`.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- Get rid of this header.  That one header alone, plus the usage of `using namespace std;` makes the program, regardless of how small it is, unpredictable if you start to introduce identifiers that happen to match what is in the `std` namespace.

Comment: You have a string of characters, not numbers. What are you trying to do? Are you `push_back()`.ing the digits?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie please can you explain more for me, I just begin to programming

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine I try to convert the string of characters into integer type using the function stoi()

Comment: @soappy [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).  You will gain experience actually *typing in* the right include header instead of copying and pasting that `<bits>` header.  Once your brain and fingers are trained to know what headers should be included, then all the better.  Also, including the `<bits>` header and the `using namespace std;` makes your program susceptible to some weird compiler errors if your code happens to use identifiers like `swap`, `gcd`, `data`, and a whole host of other identifiers.

Comment: @Quimby how can I fix that problem and improve my code

Comment: @soappy `int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++`

Comment: @Quimby -- `i <= num.length()` is **not** a buffer overflow. It still needs to be fixed, of course.

Comment: @soappy -- to convert the **text** in `str` into an integer value, just call `std::stoi(str)`. You can read about `std::stoi` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should definitely not use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` in your code. They use it in platforms like LeetCode and HackerRank but it really isn't a good practice. So, as you are starting out, try avoiding it. Check out **namespaces in C++**, this will give you a good idea.

Now, to your problem: `i <= num.length()`; here, the **=** will make you go out of range. Also `stoi` works on strings, not chars.

Here is some code to help you out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(void){
    std::vector <int> vec;

    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        vec.push_back(std::stoi(str.substr(i, 1))); // stio requires you the pass a string.
                                                    // So passing a character like str[i] won't work.
                                                    // We will need to convert each character into a substring.
    }

    return 0;
}
```