# Reading in chars and ints simultaneously as a char or should I use different types?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a function called choose. The purpose of choose is to grab input from the user and determine which function to call based on what the user has inputted. If the inputs 'x' I want to run a specific function; however, if the user inputs a certain number I want to run a function if it is less than the size of a vector. I am unsure what to define as the type for my input. I need to read in input as an int if the user types and int and as a char if the user types a char.

I originally created two variables one of type int and one of type char where I static cast the char to an int but that is getting the ascii value I believe. Im not sure how I can approach this problem. Here is what I have tried.

```
void choose(vector<string>& z){
    char x = ' ';
    do {
        cout << "Input: ";
        cin >> x;
        intX = static_cast<int>(x);

        if (x != 'x' && intX > z.size() - 1) {
            cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
            displayMenu();
        }
    } while (x != 'x' && intX > z.size() - 1);
    
    if (x == 'x'){
        doSomething(x);
    }
    else {
        doSomething(intX);
    }

}
```

Comment: read user input as `std::string` and implement your own parsing

Comment: [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030086)

Comment: You'd probably be a bit surprised if you entered 1 and `intX` contained 49.

Comment: @001 yes I've meant to change that and implement a generic example. Also, thank you for linking that reference. In what case, would you use static_cast<int>?

Comment: If you use the recommendations in 001's link, none of them.

Comment: You could use `if(x >= '0' && x <= '9') { intX = x - '0'; }`

Comment: @001 -- that highly upvoted question and answer are slightly misleading; they suffer from rampant ASCII-ism. The fact is, when `ch` holds any character that represents a digit, `ch - '0'` is **required** to give the numeric value corresponding to that digit; it does **not** depend on the encoding being ASCII. It even works for EBCDIC!

Comment: The code you might be fishing for is `if (x == 'x' || std::isdigit(x) && x - '0' < z.size()) { success } else { try again }`, which pretty clearly calls out for being written inside its own function so that the success case can simply `return x;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading in just a single `char` and then taking its numeric character value (ie, `'0'` = 48, `'1'` = 49, etc).  That is not going to accomplish what you want.

You need to read in the input as a `std::string` first, and then parse it to determine what it holds.  For example:

```
void choose(vector<string>& z){
    string x;
    do {
        cout << "Input: ";
        cin >> x;

        if (x == "x") {
            doSomething(x);
            break;
        }

        char *xEnd = nullptr;
        intX = strtol(x.c_str(), &xEnd, 10);

        if ((*xEnd == '\0') && (intX >= 0) && (intX < z.size())) {
            doSomething(intX);
            break;
        }

        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
        displayMenu();
    } while (true);
}
```