# Conversion of char to int in C?

Tags: c++, c

To convert String to integer, I know there is a function atoi()
but i found this one helps too!
Please explain this 
`int h1 = (int)str[1] - '0';`
I founded this here
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-program-convert-time-12-hour-24-hour-format/

Comment: How is this the same? And what is unclear? Everything will be explained by any beginner's C book.

Comment: Nobody's going to go through that link. Where's `str` defined? Based on the actual code, this may not even compile (or even worse).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628761/convert-a-character-digit-to-the-corresponding-integer-in-c/ explains the essence of this. '1' and '0' are (usually) next to each other so '1' - '0' is 1, '2' - '0' is 2...

Comment: Try it and you'll see that it won't work. Debug it and you'll understand why it won't work.

Comment: @doctorlove-- note that since a particular character encoding is not specified in the Standard, adjacent characters of the Latin alphabet, e.g,  need not be encoded in a contiguous sequence; you seem to be referencing this fact. [Yet, the Standard _does_ require that the characters `0,..., 9` be encoded in a contiguous sequence.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3) So, `1` and `0` are _always_ next to each other.

Comment: Cool - I learnt something

Comment: I apologize for my duplicate question and this code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically taking the second character in `str` (remember arrays are zero based) and assuming it will be in the range `'0'`..`'9'`. For this reason, it is later subtracting the ascii code of `'0'`

This will only work for a single character and it is not a replacement for `atoi`