# string to individual numbers

Tags: c, arrays, string, atoi

I ran across a problem where I need to extract each element of string to an integer array, the string only contains integer values without any space or delimiter.

Here is an example.

```
char input[8]="02320000";
```

to

`int output[8]={0,2,3,2,0,0,0,0};`

I tried to use the `atoi()` and it is taking the entire string as digit.

The string characters will be 0-3.

thank you

Comment: Do you know how to deal with individual characters in strings?

Comment: atoi() converts the string to a single integer, not an array of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can loop through all characters of the string:

```
char input[8]="02320000";
char output[8];

for(int = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    output[i] = input[i] - '0';
```

Strings in C are just sequences of characters that ends with the so called
`'\0'`-terminating byte, whose value is 0. We use `char` arrays to store them
and we use the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values for the character.

Note that `1 != '1'`. `1` is the interger one, `'1'` is the representation of
the number one. The representation has the value 49 (see [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)). If you want to calculate
the real number of a character representation, you have to use `c-'0'`, where
`c` is the character in question. That works because in the table, the values of
the numbers also are ordered as the numbers themselves: `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is
49, `'2'` is 50, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
char input[8]="02320000";
int output[8];

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
     output[i] = input[i] - '0';
}
```

explanation of the -'0' [Convert a character digit to the corresponding integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628761/convert-a-character-digit-to-the-corresponding-integer-in-c)

Comment: This got me thinking about end of string and char array initialization, so I played with it a little bit.  I learned that "02320000" seems to get implicitly cast to either (char [8]) or (char [9]) depending on whether input is char input[8] or char input[9].  I didn't expect a size of both 8 and 9 to work as seamlessly as it did.  For 8, it does not terminate the string, for 9, it does.  Of course you can't use anything smaller than 8 for the array size.