# C program to convert a decimal number to binary string

Tags: c, string

I was given this program to convert a inputted decimal number to a string which is **binary** number. Now this is a correct program and does work. I have a doubt in `while` loop the expression saying `ch = (rem + 48);` I believe value of remainder `rem` is ultimately going to be inherited by `ch` then why adding 0 ie. 48 in ascii terms is making difference. what is making addition of 48 convert `rem` to character form. If I just write `ch = rem;`, `ch` is not considered as character and adding 48 makes it charcter. But Why???

```
void main()
{
    char x[15],tmp,ch;
    int i=0,j=0,dno,rem;
    printf("\nEnter decimal number:");
    scanf("%d",&dno);
    while(dno>0)
    {
        rem = dno % 2;
        ch = (rem+48);
        x[j++] = ch;
        dno/=2;
    }
    x[j--]='\0';
    while(i<j)
    {
        tmp = x[j];
        x[j--] = x[i];
        x[i++] = tmp;
    }
    puts(x);
    return;
}
```

Comment: It is better practice (and much clearer) to use the "character literal" representation of `'0'` rather than the 'magic number' `48`! This may help (although the conversion is the other way round): https://stackoverflow.com/q/628761/10871073

Comment: thanks brother that question link helped me a lot. thanks for help.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ch` is a number that represents an ascii character value

`48` correspond to the character `"0"`

`49` correspond to the character `"1"`

the sum of `rem` (0 or 1) to 48 leads to 48 or 49, respectively the characters `"0"` and `"1"`

Answer (score 0):

In C to convert a character digit to its equivalent integer value, we can use this relationship:

```
x = character - '0'
```

Similarly to convert a digit to its equivalent character digit, we use the relationship:

```
ch = digit + '0'
```

That's why adding 48 to your `rem` makes it a character.