# Multidigit input load into an array as single digits (in C)

Tags: c, input

I need to save a user input into a 2D array in a way where the user inputs something like '123456789' and I save that input into an array so that array[0][0] == 1, array[1][2] == 6 etc. Is there something like getchar() that I could use, but for numbers?

Comment: Why not use getchar() itself?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getchar() itself, and convert it to integer using:

```
char c = getchar();
int arr[3][3];
arr[0][0] = c - '0';
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628761/convert-a-character-digit-to-the-corresponding-integer-in-c) stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Make it a habit of always using `int` with `getchar()`, since it can return `EOF`.