# Is there any simple way to store an input in vector in C++ ,other then the one i have implemented below?

Tags: c++

We were given an input which we have to store in vector and do something. The input was like this

```
123
```

Now I'm currently working on it to understand the basics and working of vector like i have learned the arrays in C lang & python. Here's what I have implemented;

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<int> v1;
  string x;
 getline(cin,x);    //takes input as string

stringstream s(x);

int temp;

for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++)
{
    char j=x[i];    //Iterating over each n every string
    int num;
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<j;
    ss>>num;     //covert the string to integer
    v1.push_back(num);
}

for(auto i=v1.begin();i!=v1.end();++i)    //output
    cout<<*i<<" ";
return 0;
```

}

After runnung this i will get output of vector like this:

```
1 2 3
```

Is there any easy way to implement this like in python we use `.split()`?

Comment: So you want to split each digit apart?

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to take a string like `"123"` as input and store the numeric value of each digit in a `vector<int>`? Or is there any further logic to it?

Comment: In Python, `"123".split()` is not `["1", "2", "3"]`.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell whether there is a better way without a better description than "an input which we have to store in vector and do something" of what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: Thank u Guys my question has been resolved ,Please read the below comments!Sorry for my poor explanation I'm new to SO .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's **guaranteed** that the input only consists of digits only, then you can use `std::cin` to input, then minus each character by `'0'` to get the integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string inp;
    std::cin >> inp;

    std::vector<int>result;
    for (char c : inp) { result.push_back(c - '0'); }
    for (int x : result) {std::cout << x << " ";}
}
```

Result:

```
1237790
1 2 3 7 7 9 0
```

Else you can use `std::getline` (so some spaces maybe added to the input) to input, then use [`isdigit()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) to check whether a character is a digit :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string inp;
    std::getline(std::cin, inp);

    std::vector<int>result;
    for (char c : inp)
    {
        if (isdigit(c)) {result.push_back(c - '0');}
    }
    for (int x : result) {std::cout << x << " ";}
}
```

Result:

```
abc  123 /*78awd00
1 2 3 7 8 0 0
```

Some explanation :

In C++ programming language, the [`char` data type](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/chars/) is an integral type, meaning the underlying value is stored as an integer. More specifically, the integer stored by a char variable are interpreted as an **ASCII** character : [ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html).

As you can see, digit `char` is represented from `48` to `57`, starting from `'0'` and ending with `'9'`.

So when we take a digit `char` `c`, for example `'2'`, and minus it by `'0'`, we're quite literally substracting the ASCII value of `'2'`, which is `50`, to `'0'`, which is `48`, and we end up with an integer that we needed : `2`.

Similar post : [Convert a character digit to the corresponding integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628761/convert-a-character-digit-to-the-corresponding-integer-in-c)

So you can see that using `stringstream` instead of a simple substraction is quite an overkill (but it works anyway, no objection there):

```
char j=x[i]; 
int num;
stringstream ss;
ss<<j;
ss>>num;
```

Note that `using namespace std;` and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is highly warned against:

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: U r real gem thankssss for  replying.Also Thanks*1000 for elite level explanation.My all doubts are totally destroyed after reading ur each n every line......

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but conceptually could look like that

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string num_str; // will hold the whole number as string
    cin >> num_str;
    vector<int> digits;
    for(auto digit_ch : num_str) {
        digits.push_back(digit_ch - '0');
    }
}
```

The trick is in this line `digits.push_back(digit_ch - '0');` where you iterate every digit as a char (like `'2'` or `'5'`), and by subtracting `'0'` from it, you get a numerical value of this digit (`2` and `5` respectively)

Comment: Wooooowwww.......Cant belive my eyes, wht i did in 50 lines u did that in 10 line.Thank u soo much for replying!!!!! Really liked ur code,Short n sweer

Comment: @Joel_RDJ By the way in competitive programming it's sometimes useful when you have alphabet characters which define order, and you can easily convert `ABC...XYZ` into `0 1 2 ... 23 24 25` by again subtracting from each char `A`. This trick uses the fact that in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) capital letters are represented in a sequence, so e.g. code for `A` is 65, and for `B` it's 66 and so on. By subtracting `A` from another capital letter, you essentially get how far away this letter is from `A` in ASCII table (so `A` is 0 away from `A`, `B` is 1 away from `A` as so on)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) which can iterate over each character in `inp` and then with the use of a lambda, check if the character is a digit, and if so, add it to `result`, e.g.

```
    std::for_each (inp.begin(), inp.end(), [&result](int c) { 
                                            if (isdigit(c)) 
                                                result.push_back(c - '0');
                                            });
```

The example validating the input and using `std::for_each()` could be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string inp;
    std::vector<int>result;
    
    if (std::getline (std::cin, inp)) {
        std::for_each (inp.begin(), inp.end(), [&result](int c) { 
                                                if (isdigit(c)) 
                                                    result.push_back(c - '0');
                                                });
    }
        
    for (int x : result) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout.put ('\n');
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5" | ./bin/for_each_digit
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Sure, glad to help, there are many, many ways this can be handled. None, necessarily better than the other so long as they are relatively efficient and correct.