# Insert integer into the middle of string c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to replace the W with the number 5 (in this example).  However, when I try, I only get the the ascii value of 5 to replace the W, instead of the number 5 itself.    How would I fix this?
NOTE: I this is a shortened example from a longer project.  I need to access the number in nums[1].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nums[3] {4,5,6};
    string str = "HELLO WORLD";

    cout << str << endl;
    str[6] = nums[1];
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
HELLO WORLD
HELLO ♣ORLD

Comment: Try with `int num0 = '5';`

Comment: because string is an array of `char`s, which are integers with values interpreted as characters. And `num0` is also an integer. So you are inserting a integer of value `5`, which maps to you see what.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a character digit to the corresponding integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628761/convert-a-character-digit-to-the-corresponding-integer-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a digit to an ASCII character: `char c = '0' + 5` (gives you `'5'`).
This is your code fixed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nums[3] {4,5,6};
    string str = "HELLO WORLD";

    cout << str << endl;
    str[6] = '0' + nums[1];
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

However, if you intend to insert an **integer** as you title says, you have to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nums[3] {4,15,6};
    string str = "HELLO WORLD";

    cout << str << endl;
    // str = str.substr(0, 6) + std::to_string(nums[1]) + str.substr(7);
    str.replace(6, 1, std::to_string(nums[1])); // as Remy Lebeau has mentioned in the comments
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

(UPD: it is equivalent to `std::string::replace`)
Here is a more sophisticated version which tries to use existing capacity:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// don't ever do it with std
// using namespace std;

size_t count_digits(int num)
{
    int digits = 0; 
    do { 
        num /= 10; 
        digits++; 
    } while (num);
    return digits;
}

void insert_number(std::string& str, size_t indx, int num)
{
    const size_t digits = count_digits(num),
        oldSize = str.size();
    
    // insert will reallocate only if capacity is not enough
    str.insert(str.size(), digits - 1, '0');

    // move the end of string right by rotating (rewriting characters)
    auto iterBegin = std::next(str.begin(), indx),
        iterNext = std::next(str.begin(), oldSize);
    std::rotate(iterBegin, iterNext, str.end());

    // write our string from integer to the designated space
    const auto &strInteger = std::to_string(num);
    for (size_t iStr = indx, iInt = 0; iInt != strInteger.size(); ++iInt, ++iStr)
        str[iStr] = strInteger[iInt];
}

int main()
{
    int nums[3] {4, 48152342, 6};
    std::string str = "HELLO WORLD LOOOOONG STRIIING";
    str.reserve(str.capacity() + 20); // strings don't preallocate more space after construction

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "capacity before: " << str.capacity() << std::endl;
    insert_number(str, 6, nums[1]);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "capacity after: " << str.capacity() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7aPMvcosj

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!!!!

Comment: @Austin I've updated my answer for integers

Comment: @Austin the second one is naive:) It would lead to reallocation. One should check for `capacity` first. If you can get around without allocating space, then copy chars to the end and rewrite those required in the middle

Comment: @Austin read about `std::basic_string::capacity`. Reallocation is not necessary if the integer is not large.

Comment: @Austin I've added a version that takes capacity into an account

Comment: `str = str.substr(0, 6) + std::to_string(nums[1]) + str.substr(7);` can be simplified using `string::replace()`, eg: `str.replace(6, 1, std::to_string(nums[1]);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau take a closer look into that example. `nums[1]` returns `15`

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik And, your point is? [`string::replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) replaces an X-length substring with a Y-length substring.  So it can replace 1 char with 2 chars.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I stand corrected

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to store an `int` where a `char` is expected. Integer `5` (interpreted as character `'♣'` in your console's charset) and character `'5'` (integer `53` in ASCII) are not the same value.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch0 = '5';
    string str = "HELLO WORLD";

    cout << str << endl;
    str[6] = ch0;
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear - in short, I cannot due that, because what I posted was a hypothetical example.  Thanks for trying!